# Unity3d particle system поворот частиц

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Добавил систему частиц на движущийся объект. Объект всегда смотрит по направлению движения(полет ракеты).
Позади объекта создаются частицы, но при отскоке объекта от стены, все частицы, даже уже созданные, меняют угол поворота на равный новому направлению движения объекта.
Как сделать так, чтобы поворот уже выпущенных частиц не зависел от угла поворота родительского объекта?

Добавлю картинку:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqLSi.jpg

Ссылка на настройки:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPfpe.jpg

Получается две проблемы, либо выпущенные частицы не зависят от угла поворота совсем, т.е. могут лететь перпендикулярно движению ракеты, либо они меняют угол поворота, как я описал вначале

Воспользовался trail renderer'ом - эффект не совсем такой, но близкий к нужному, вопрос можно считать закрытым

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Симуляцию надо в мировых координатах производить

Comment: Не помогло, все точно также

Comment: Вот возьми дефолтный партикл и посмотри на нем, не знаю что ты там крутишь, хоть бы скриншотов сделал

Comment: @DeRibura скрины настроек